# Node-RED seems to fail to connect to Cloudant

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, node-red

An existing Node-RED App failed to start on Bluemix.

I'm getting the following errors:

```
DEA/2 Starting app instance (index 0) with guid ----
App/0 Failed to find Cloudant service
App/0 Error loading settings file: /home/vcap/app/bluemix-settings.js
```

The Cloudant service is working and accessible via the Bluemix Web interface.
The VCAP_Services variable is visible in the web interface and seems to be OK.

The only recent change is the name of the App in Bluemix.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by renaming the App with it's original name.

Lesson: Never change an Node-RED application display name (not the route) other you may end in trouble.